# Animation concept of every section hardware from Mac Pro website is done by css3 + js?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi all I was wondering how did apple did their hardware animation on their website http://www.apple.com/mac-pro/

Does anyone knows how this is done? css3 or purely js or html5 video? the container seems to be at .placeholder-inner

Comment: In the source code of the page there are video elements and image elements, so I bet it is a mix of everything, using javascript to synchronize.

Answer (score 2):

This is done by trigging HTML5 video at specific scroll points.

See the asset here:
http://movies.apple.com/media/us/mac-pro/2013/16C1b6b5-1d91-4fef-891e-ff2fc1c1bb58/videos/macpro_main_desktop.mp4